# Vue check two computed ready

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

every time i need to know when several computed values are ready, i write another computed (e.g. isFizzAndBuzzReady)

```
computed: {
  fizz () {
    return ['f', 'i', 'z', 'z'] // some async data
  },
  buzz () {
    return ['b', 'u', 'z', 'z'] // some async data
  },
  isFizzAndBuzzReady () {
    return this.fizz.length && this.buzz.length
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to check they are both ready?

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: with @RoyJ ^, assuming those are arrays and they are empty at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed is the best way to do this.

The other way is to do it with `$watch` but it is imperative and repetitive.